# How can I delete album in objective C/Iphone development?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I 'd like to ask a question about iOS, do you know if it possible to delete a album programmatically? I use the "addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName" in the assets library to add new custom album, but cannot find the way to delete album. There are no method declared in the alassetslibrary
Hope some one know the answer...
Thanks!

Comment: Is this a joke question? You can't just go in and delete the user's iTunes library, apps don't work that way.

Comment: I would make an app that keeps removing user album randomly.

Answer (score 1):

No ,Its not possible to delete albums in photo library programmatically. See [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1413776?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Well you can create, but not delete.

Comment: Thanks for all that answering me...I have search such related information for several days but no clear answer...now it seems cannot delete the album...